# How to pass object values in as an array of props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, syntax, jsx

I have a react button component that pulls in button classnames from a module.scss file.
It works just fine if I want to select a single style/class from my object, but I can't figure out how to display multiple (in the case I want to use augment classes). I have tried fiddling around with arrays but can't seem to get it.

Button.jsx component code

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./button.module.scss";
import Link from "next/link";

const {
  buttonPrimary,
  buttonSecondary,
  buttonTertiary,
  smallButton
} = styles;

export const Button = ({
                         variant = "primary",
                         label,
                         href,
                         ...props // allows for other custom props
                       }) => {
  const variants = {
    primary: buttonPrimary,
    secondary: buttonSecondary,
    tertiary: buttonTertiary,
    small: smallButton
  };

    return (
      <Link href={href ? href : "#"}>
        <a className={${variants[variant]}}>
          {label}
        </a>
      </Link>
    );
};
```

Component usage in jsx page:

```
<Button label={'Test'} variant={'primary'}/>
```

Desired outcome would be to have multiple variants selectable from the list, so we can combine them E.G.:

```
<Button label={'Test'} variant={['primary', 'small']} />
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `map` the variants to the class names from the scss module. (And separate them with spaces)

```
const classNames = variant.map(v =>  variants[v]).join(' ')
```

In your component it'd be:

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./button.module.scss";
import Link from "next/link";

const {
  buttonPrimary,
  buttonSecondary,
  buttonTertiary,
  smallButton
} = styles;

export const Button = ({
                         variant = "primary",
                         label,
                         href,
                         ...props // allows for other custom props
                       }) => {
  const variants = {
    primary: buttonPrimary,
    secondary: buttonSecondary,
    tertiary: buttonTertiary,
    small: smallButton
  };

    return (
      <Link href={href ? href : "#"}>
        <a className={variant.map(v => variants[v]).join(' ')}>
          {label}
        </a>
      </Link>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep the possibilities to pass one element outside of an array you can do something like this :

```js
return (
  <Link href={href ? href : "#"}>
    <a className={[variant].flat().map((current) => variants[current]).join(' '))}>
      {label}
    </a>
  </Link>
);
```

What this does is :

- Put the `variant` prop in a array
- Use the `flat` method to transform an eventual 2D array to a 1D array (So `[['primary']]` become `['primary']` for example (a 1D array remains a 1D array)
- Use the `map` method to get an array of the differents variants (each return value replace the current element)
- Transform the final array into a string, separating each element with an empty space